# Input type number with plus, minus or "e" inside shows empty value, why?

Tags: javascript, input

I've set input type to "number" and now I want to apply some validations to it. I want to prevent starting the function (after clicking the button) if the input contains "+", "-" or "e".

```js
const countBtn = document.getElementById("forge-points-btn");

function quantityHandler() {
    let userInput = document.querySelector(".forge-points-input").value;
    if(userInput.split("").includes("e") || userInput.split("").includes("-")) {
        return;
    }
    // else code
    }
```

```html
    <input type="number" class="forge-points-input" id="forge-points-input"></input>
    <button type="button" id="forge-points-btn">Count</button>
```

But to my surprise, it doesn't work because when minus, plus or "e" are entered, e.g. "321-51", "+e-", etc. then `userInput` equals to empty string. However, when "-55" is entered, then `userInput` displays correct value. Why is that happening? I'm trying to figure out why can't this solution work. I've seen other solutions on this forum, yet I'd like to understand why this one can't work.

Comment: `e` stand for exponential values ?

Answer (score 2):

The [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#validation) states:

> `<input type="number">` elements automatically invalidate any entry that isn't a number (or empty, unless `required` is specified).

You can see this for yourself: providing a value that is not a number automatically invalidates the field.

```html
<p>Equations are not numbers.</p>
<input type="text" id="text-input" value="123-456">
<input type="number" id="number-input" value="123-456">

<p>Signed numbers are numbers.</p>
<input type="number" id="number-input" value="-123">
<input type="number" id="number-input" value="+123">

<p>Exponents are numbers.</p>
<input type="number" id="exponent-input" value="10e5">
```

---

If you want to disallow `+`, `-`, and `e` in your `input[type=number]` then your approach is correct. You must also check that the input is valid, however.

```
if (!userInput?.length || userInput.includes("e") || ...)
```

(Side note, you don't need to `.split("")` since JavaScript can coerce a `number` into a `string`.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! By the way you've learned me how to learn, I need to check documentation more often while getting into troubles. I used `.split()` method since I thought it can be applied only to arrays, but as I can see it works with strings as well :)